# Redirecting form fails

Tags: javascript, cakephp, controller

I'm having problems with my forms redirection for a specific controller. In my database table it called `lists_acciones`.

Model :

```
<?php
 App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
 App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
 /**
 * ListAccione Model
 *
 */
 class ListAccione extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'lists_acciones';
```

Controller

```
<?php
  App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
  /**
  * ListsAcciones Controller
  *
  * @property Menu $Menu
  */
  class ListsAccioneController extends AppController {
```

I can access any function from my controller and the controller is the url `listsAccione`

Now he was creating a form, then click the go to the index view but the controller that comes is `lists_acciones`

```
echo $this->Form->create('ListsAccione', array(
    'action' => 'index',
    'class' => 'form_center',
    'id'=>'formulario_busqueda',
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'label' => false,
        'div'   => false,
        # define error defaults for the form
        'error' => array(
            'wrap'  => 'span', 
            'class' => 'my-error-class'
        )
    )
));
```

From Javascript

```
var url = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array(
    'controller' => 'listsAccione',
    'action' => 'index',
    'admin'=>true));?>/page:"+pagina;

$('#formulario_busqueda').attr('action',url); //this works
```

Comment: You can't call PHP from within JavaScript like that as JavaScript runs client-side, not server-side!

Comment: @drmonkeyninja Thanks for your advice, but it was only to test whether or not served redirection, that's not part of my code anyway still can not solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the documentation [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html)

```
'url' => ['controller' => 'listsAccione', 'action' => 'index'],
```